# rest library for android

Tags: android, android-volley

I was looking for `REST API` Handling for Android.

Somebody has recommended for [Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Its description is fairly simple but I am getting class not found `exception` at run time.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

I have downloaded the jar from [here](http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley.jar)

I could not able to make jar from command line explained in the example.

Should I go with other `REST API` like ***RoboSpice***, ***Spring framework***, etc.

Comment: I´d go for plain httpclient

Answer (score 1):

You are already having `.jar` file. You don't have to compile anything. You have to add this library to your `libs` folder, `Right click` it and select 'Add as library'.

Take a look at [Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). You can make your `REST client` using it.